# What version of Tensorflow federated has the module 'federated_computation'?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I am trying to install Tensorflow federated on google collab, but there is a conflict with versions, I either get this error if I install previous versions or similar errors.

```
module tensorflow_federated.python has no attribute federated_computation
```

If I want to install the new version it gives the "this requires this version but you have this version" during the installation.
I am very confused. Is there an easy way to use Tensorflow federated learning? I tried to install it locally but that also didn't work.
Why is it so hard to use it?

[image]

[image]

If I uninstalled all packages and installed them again it gives me the error mentioned above

If I try to import it ignoring the errors in the pictures it gives me this error with a newer version

```
'type' object is not subscribable
```

And this error with version 20

```
module 'tensorflow_federated.python' has no attribute 'federated_computation'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that

1. you need to install Tensorflow federated learning version 0.20.0

```
!pip install --quiet tensorflow-federated==0.20.0
```

2. Ignore the dependency error
3. Instead of the below

```
from tensorflow_federated import python as tff
```

use:

```
import tensorflow_federated as tff
```